# change the font color gridview row based on a columns value. cant index gridviewrow?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, sqldatasource

i am getting a syntax error at drr(5) which 5 is the column i want to base the color change on.
this method works when i am using a dataset

```
Dim Land As String = "Land"
        Dim Air As String = "Air"
        Dim Cruise As String = "Cruise"

        Dim y As String

        For Each drr As gridviewrow In GridView2.Rows
            y = drr(5).ToString()
            If y = Land Then
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen
            ElseIf y = Air Then
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            ElseIf y = Cruise Then
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
            End If


        Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim a As String = GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text
```

use `Text` variable , that is the cell text word.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access a cell in a grid view row, you should use the cell property of the row. In your example you need to write **drr.Cells(5).ToString()**
As in

```
Dim Land As String = "Land"
    Dim Air As String = "Air"
    Dim Cruise As String = "Cruise"

    Dim y As String

    For Each drr As gridviewrow In GridView2.Rows
        y = drr.Cells(5).ToString()
        If y = Land Then
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen
        ElseIf y = Air Then
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        ElseIf y = Cruise Then
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        End If


    Next
```

Also I find that it's better to give the row a class and then change the color using css.

Comment: wierd no syntax error but the color is still showing as black

Answer (score 0):

You should apply a CssClass according to this value:

for example:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindGrid()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32)).AutoIncrement = True
    dt.Columns.Add("Style", GetType(String))
    dt.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dt.Columns("ID")}
    Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    newRow("Style") = "Land"
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
    newRow = dt.NewRow
    newRow("Style") = "Air"
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
    newRow = dt.NewRow
    newRow("Style") = "Cruise"
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
    Me.GridView1.DataSource = dt
    Me.GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub    

Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim dr As DataRow = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row
        e.Row.CssClass = DirectCast(dr("Style"), String)
    End If
End Sub
```

The important part is in RowDataBound that is called automatically if you bind the GridView. If you don't want to name the CssClass exactly like the text that is displayed, you could use `If...Else` or `Select Case` to set the CSS-Class.

Comment: the problem is i am using an sqldatasource, i am not manually coding the connection and sql, im not creating the datatable

Comment: Nevertheles `RowDataBound` will be called implicitely. Have a look at following MSDN-Link for further informations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Answer (score 0):

And about changing the TableCells? This doen't work too?

```
gridview.Rows[0].Cells[0].ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0000FF");
```

In C#, but give a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub grdUsers_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As    System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdUsers.RowDataBound
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        For Each row As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
            If e.Row.Cells(11).Text = "Approved" Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To 11
                    e.Row.Cells(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                Next
            End If
            If e.Row.Cells(11).Text = "Rejected" Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To 11
                    e.Row.Cells(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```