# Change gridview row forecolor based on column field value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a value in one of my gridview column which will determine if the entire row's value should be in red color. I did the below but somehow every single row is red colored. Please kindly advice. Thanks.

```
Protected Sub uigvList_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles uigvList.RowCreated

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If Not (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "VoidOn")) Is Nothing Then ' This is the condition, if this field is not blank then I want to the entire row to have red colored values.
            e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Firebrick
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867283/change-the-font-color-gridview-row-based-on-a-columns-value-cant-index-gridview

Comment: can you try RowDataBound event instead of RowCreated and apply color to each cell and not the whole row at once, because applying color to row `<tr>` tag is not valid in some browsers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **DBNull.Value**?

```
If (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "VoidOn")) IsNot DBNull.Value Then ...
```

```
If e.Row.DataItem("VoidOn") IsNot DBNull.Value Then ...
```

PS: You can check **VoidOn** value in the debug mode, just set breakpoint to the code row.